# extreme value labels in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, boxplot, geom-text

I am trying to add the labels for extreme values (outliers or not) on geom_box plots. 
I found this question, which is almost exactly similar to mine [ [extreme value labels ggplot2 in geom_boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910748/extreme-value-labels-ggplot2-in-geom-boxplot) ]
The answer provided by yonicd almost works for me:

```
df=rbind(data.frame(id=rep("1",100),var=paste0("V",seq(1,100)),
         val=rnorm(100,0,5)),
         data.frame(id=rep("2",100),var=paste0("V",seq(1,100)),
         val=rnorm(100,0,3)))


df_bound=df%.%group_by(id)%>%do(.,data.frame(val=boxplot.stats(.$val)$out))
df_bound=left_join(df_bound, df, by=c("id","val"))

ggplot(df,aes(x=id, y=val, fill=id, label=var)) + geom_boxplot() +
geom_point(aes(group=id), data=df_bound)+
geom_text(aes(group=id), data=df_bound, hjust=-1, size=4)
```

It seems obvious that I would just need to replace the [ $out] in

```
 df_bound=df%.%group_by(id)%>%do(.,data.frame(val=boxplot.stats(.$val)$out))
```

to have the extreme values instead of the outliers.
If I use

```
df_bound=df%.%group_by(id)%>%do(.,data.frame(val=boxplot.stats(.$val)$stats))
```

the labels for the outliers don't appear.
How could if fix that?

Comment: I reckon it's because the conf values ("the lower and upper extremes of the ‘notch’") are calculated (if I got that correctly from `?boxplot.stats`) and not values found in `df`, hence the join cannot work.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the post accordingly.
If I use [ $stats ] instead, the labels are the extreme values of the whiskers.

Answer (score 0):

So code works with latest version of dplyr: change the `%.%` operator to a magrittr pipe `%>%`. Added [c(1,5)] which subsets the 'lower' and 'upper' extremes of the whiskers in boxplot.stats$stats.

`df_bound <- df%>%group_by(id)%>%do(.,data.frame(val=boxplot.stats(.$val)$stats[c(1,5)]))`

Comment: Is this a complete answer to the problem stated in the question? It reads more like a long comment.